# Can't resolve all parameters for Location

Tags: angular

I upgraded to Angulr9 (ssr) and enabled Ivy.
but I got the error `Can't resolve all parameters for Location`
I don't use the service 'Location' at all, and all services uses `@Injectable`

anyway, the error trace doesn't show clearly wher is the source of this error.

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Location: (?, ?).
    at syntaxError (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\almogtama3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:2845:21)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\almogtama3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23397:39)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\almogtama3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23289:30)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableTypeMetadata (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\almogtama3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23515:25)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\almogtama3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23524:26)
    at D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\almogtama3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23462:53
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\almogtama3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23419:23)
    at D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\almogtama3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23421:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\almogtama3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23419:23)
    at D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\almogtama3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23038:76
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\almogtama3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23029:53)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\almogtama3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:22964:39)
    at D:\Downloads\__projects\dev\NodeJs\almogtama3\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23051:59
```

reproduction: 
https://github.com/goblins-tech/almogtama3/tree/tmp

run `npm run build:browser:dev && npm run build:server:dev && npm run serve:inspect`

Comment: I got the exact same problem.
I don't know if it will help you but when I add `import 'reflect-metadata';` in my _server.ts_ (_express.ts_ for you if I'm not mistaken), I don't have this error anymore. Is it better or worse? I can't tell for the moment, but it will maybe lead us to some new hints.